# Query formula to add a column in Month/Year format from existing date values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a data set where 1 of the columns contains dates in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.  I'd like to use a single query formula to select some columns from that data set, including the date column.  That's not an issue, however I'd also like to use the same/one formula to add an extra column to the output converting the existing date format into "Long month, Year" format.  Preferably this can be done so that the final column is not a TEXT format.

I have this sheet containing the sample data set, small sample of what I tried, and the desired output
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MdeiGKQduOWeCYUrioi_THl3VgNw4jciE28qzklynP8/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, joining a second query with that A column repeated, and just format that column with month large and year

> ={QUERY(Data_Set!1:1000,"SELECT A,C"),QUERY(Data_Set!1:1000,"SELECT A")}

You can see it in a copy of"Best I could do" sheet ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
=QUERY(Data_Set!1:1000,"select A,C,todate(A) label todate(A) 'Long month, Year' format todate(A) 'MMMM, yyyy' ",1)
```

TEST sheet in your file